# Make entire document look heavier using pdfrender package

Tags: fonts, pdftex

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pdfrender,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\pdfrender{StrokeColor=black,TextRenderingMode=2,LineWidth=0.2pt}

\end{document}
```

I am using this code, i want entire document to be same.
For example, figure titles are NOT coming darker, the page numbers in table of contents NOT darker, numbering of equation arrays NOT darker, etc. I am using TexStudio for typing my thesis.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a feature. Package `pdfrender` redefines `\normalcolor` to reset the "normal" behavior. For example, there is some emphasized text via `\pdfrender` and a page break occurs. Then the header and footer should have normal rendering.

I must admit, the idea, that someone wants to set whole documents with `\pdfrender` didn't cross my mind, when I wrote `pdfrender`. But it is
possible. The package add the hook `\PdfRender@NormalColorHook` to reset the normal behaviour. This hook can be redefined to be an empty macro. The original meaning of the hook is kept in `\normalrender`. That allows normal rendering for included images.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdfrender,xcolor}

\makeatletter
\let\normalrender\PdfRender@NormalColorHook
\let\PdfRender@NormalColorHook\@empty
\newcommand*{\textnormalrender}[1]{%
  \begingroup\normalrender#1\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\pdfrender{StrokeColor=blue,TextRenderingMode=2,LineWidth=0.2pt}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{A section title}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\textnormalrender{Normal rendering mode for graphics.}
% \textnormalrender{\includegraphics{...}}
\caption{This is a figure title.}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
E=mc^2 \label{eq:einstein}
\end{equation}

References: figure \ref{fig} and equation \ref{eq:einstein}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: @H. Oberdiek, i appreciate thanks for your help. But my figures' titles and labels within eps file are now so big and dark, that i cant read in pdf file, i do hope you understand. What i do now for figures? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good Job, it works!

Comment: Adequately dark is the new normal in Latex!

Comment: @H. Oberdiek, I've found out that this does not work for footnote numbers and numbers on the footnotes themselves if one uses the package ocgx2 for its "ocgcolorlinks" option and "breaklinks=true"; but setting it to false restores heavier stroking. I'm exhausted after figuring out this gotcha; so maybe someone else can follow up. Just the numbers come out with the normal light stroking. The rest of the text is fine. I'll just use this, and change link color & get rid of underline for hard-copy.

Comment: Horizontal lines in math are not affected and appear too thin though. For example, fractions and the horizontal line in the square root sign appear unaffected. Is there a way to fix this? (in your example, they would be completely blue, not black with a blue border)

Comment: @MonteCarlo Package `pdfrender` uses a PDF font feature for its effects. However, TeX uses simple rules unrelated to fonts for the horizontal lines, when constructing the fraction line, underline, or overline, for example. That is not in the scope of this PDF font feature.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying.